# Amplify.observe not updating based on changes to DynamoDB

Tags: android, aws-amplify

I am currently making a call to my server to make a change in the Datastore and listening for another change to it. I do not receive any new changes from the DB despite the database being changed correctly on the backend.
I recently upgraded amplify from 1.4.2 to 1.6.8 and this is when the issue started to show up.

```
Amplify.DataStore.observe(Profile::class.java,
        { observationCancelable ->
//ERROR
        },
        { changedItem ->
            when (changedItem.item().state) {
//DO Business logic
            }
        },
        { exception ->
            //ERROR
        },
        {
        }
        )
```

When I query the datastore I am getting outdated results that are not the same as the data on DynamoDB. Is there any way to figure out why the local datastore is not being updated? Could it be an issue with the configuration with the server? Or is there some setup step that I have missed?

Edit: Added some extra details below

So a few more details I wanted to add to this that seem way more relevant as well as updates based on my research. I am switching between endpoints(dev to testing environments). It would seem that the dev environment is working fine with the application, using the datastore correctly and doing the proper AppSync. But in the new testing environment, when the app starts, it gets the latest version of the datastore but it fails to do any AppSync despite being able to make changes to the backend.

Here is an error I am getting when the app attempts to subscribe to the Profile object in the back end

```
amplify:aws-datastore: Unauthorized failure for ON_CREATE Profile
amplify:aws-datastore: Releasing latch due to an error: Subscription error for Profile: [GraphQLResponse.Error{message='Not Authorized to access onCreateProfile on type Subscription', locations='null', path='null', extensions='{errorType=Unauthorized}'}]
```

Is there some config file that I should be looking at to compare with to make sure that the endpoints match or some access key that the app needs?

Comment: Hi @punkfusion92. I'd suggest joining us on Discord, or creating a question on our GitHub repo. https://discord.gg/amplify or https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-android/issues. It looks like you're using an `@auth` directive to restrict access to one of your models. My guess is that the two environments were provisioned differently, in some way.

Comment: Hi @Jameson I actually just figured out the issue. It was totally on my end caused due to a mismatch of amplify models. codegen and codegen model commands were not finding the correct schema on the project due to an error in the amplify project itself. It was storing the file in the app resource folder instead of the amplify one and hence those commands would not update the models correctly. Thank you for the invite as well